# How does Donald B. Johnson's algorithm work with limited cycle length?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have learned that the algorithm published in 1975 by Donald B. Johnson is an efficient way to find all cycles in directed graph. But now I have a very large graph but only need find cycles with limited length. How to modify it to do that?

Comment: Johnson's algorithm is overkill if all you're trying to do is detect the presence of cycles. Assuming you don't care about edge/cycle weight, DFS would be simpler and faster.

Comment: @beaker My edges don't have weight. I want to print all directed cycles with length less than a limit. Will DFS faster than johnson's algorithm? I think it has least time complexity.

Comment: From my previous comment, "DFS would be simpler and faster."

Answer (score 0):

First, It may be easier to implement with dfs(still need to be practice).
Second, You can consider counting all nodes with distance less than limit length from startnode when you compute the strong connected compnents, but this may increace the time complexity.
Finally, You can take advantage of multithreading or parallel computing, I hope you can reach the final in CodeCraft2020.